# Implementing SESSION persistent state with React components and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to React and I am attempting to implement a persistent state for sessions using firebase for a personal project. I currently have within the auth.js file:

```
export const sessionState = (email, password) => {
  auth.setPersistence(auth.Persistence.SESSSION)
  .then(() =>
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
)};
```

But it's still loading with a local state persistence, I've looked at the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: You have to put the `return` no ?

Comment: I initially tried that following the documentation, but it fails to compile on my local machine.

Comment: SESSION should save the Auth state in sessionStorage. Check sessionStorage to confirm.

Comment: Checkout this one for [how to use local storage in React to persist a Firebase session](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-firebase-auth-persistence/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the perspective of a Firebase app, the session of your app is driven by the authentication state of the user. If there is no authentication in use at all, then your app will be 100% responsible for that, i.e. localstorage or cookies.

So, in the Firebase's model, the `.onAuthStateChanged` observer should drive the initialState and state of your component.

Comment: Thank you! This helped along with the comment from @bojeil.